# .htaccess rule for 301 redirect to absolute url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL and want to redirect to an absolute url. The following doesn't work for me:

```
Redirect 301 /changecurrency/3?returnurl=/9ct-gold-belcher-chain-tg40dc http://www.example.com/9ct-gold-belcher-chain-tg40dc
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: The http get parameters are _not_ part of the URL. If you need to match exactly that request you try (with exactly those get parameters), then you need to use a `Rewriteond` s offered by the rewriting module.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http get parameters are not part of the URL. If you need to match exactly that request you try (with exactly those get parameters), then you need to use a Rewriteond s offered by the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} returnurl=/9ct-gold-belcher-chain-tg40dc
RewriteRule ^/?changecurrency/3 http://www.example.com/9ct-gold-belcher-chain-tg40dc [END,R=301,QSD]
```

The above rule will work in the http servers host configuration and also in dynamic coniguration files (`.htaccess`).

Obviously the rewriting module has to be loaded into the http server.

In case you are using a really old version of the apache http server you might have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Nice answer +1 but I dont think you should use END for external Redirection.

Comment: @starkeen Always willing to learn... would you care to elaborate?

Comment: END flag is mainly used with internal rewriteRules to terminate the rule's processing. It has nothing to do with an external request as in your example.

Comment: @starkeen Sure, I know that. Question is if it is redundant here. That is the case if an external redirection ends the rewrite process anyway. I am not certain, actually, though that does make sense...

Comment: @arkascha - that works fine but I don't want the query string appended to the resulting url. Can the query string be dropped?

Comment: @Owen Append a single `?` to the end of the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ to drop the query string from the resulting URL (or use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+).

Comment: Regarding the `END` vs `L` debate... In my experience `END` and `L` behave exactly the same when it comes to _external redirects_ (`R` flag), despite what the docs appear to suggest. The external redirect occurs immediately (or rather, after the first round of processing). However, [the docs for the `L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) seem to contradict this, "if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal **or external** - causing the request process to start over." In my tests the request process does not "start over" for _external_ redirects?